# (Ruby on Rails) Trying To Edit A Post Using Partials But Having Problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making a bloglike application. I want to make it so that blog posts are editable if clicked.

This is my partial that displays all the posts of a user and makes them clickable

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
<% @feed_items.in_groups_of(3, false).each do |feeds| %>
<div class="row">
  <% feeds.each do |feed| %>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <ol class="posts">
    <%= link_to edit_post_path(feed) do %>
 <%= render feed %>
 <% end %>
      </ol>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

This is the Edit view that it redirects to when a post is clicked:

```
<% if logged_in? %>
<div class="row">
    <%= render 'shared/post_form' %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

And this is the '_post_form' partial which is the layout for an editable post:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
<div class="field">
<%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new post..." %>
</div>
<%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

When I click a post to edit it it does redirect however it gives me the error: "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty"

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: Can show your controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller's edit method you have to set @post like,

def edit

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
```

end